# Moving Feedburner to a new domain

Tags: wordpress, rss, feeds, feedburner

I have a Wordpress blog (running Feedsmith plugin) that uses Feedburner for email and RSS subscribers.

Currently this blog is located at `http://www.myblog.com`.

I will be moving this Wordpress blog to a new domain as follows

`http://newdomain.com/blog`

I wonder if anyone could give me a suggestion on how to edit my Feedburner settings to avoid losing subscirbers.

I've read that in the **"Edit Feed Details..."** panel of Feedburner one should change:

**Feed Title**: New Blog Title

**Original Feed**: `http://newdomain.com/blog/feed`

**Feed Address**: ***what should this be changed to?***

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the feed address same and just edit the original feed detail. You won't lose the subscribers.

Answer (score 2):

In feedburner settings, change the feed address from http://myblog.com/feed to: http://newdomain.com/blog/feed.

No subscribers should be lost.

Only do this after your other site is running!